# Injector not working as expected in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have defined a service as follows:

```
//storageService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    storage: any;

    constructor() {
        this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
    }

    getUser() {
        return this.storage.get('user');
    }

}
```

I am injecting this in another Class as below:

```
Profile.ts
import {StorageService} from '../../services/storageService';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/profile.html',
    providers: [StorageService]
})
export class ProfilePage {


    constructor(private http: Http, storageService: StorageService)  {
        this.storageService.getUser().then(user => {
          this.user = JSON.parse(user);  
        }).catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
        });

    }

}
```

However i keep receiving the error:

```
Cannot read property 'getUser' of undefined
```

since I am injecting the service in the constructor..howcome I am getting this error ?

Comment: Did you add `providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]` in `@App(...)`?

Comment: there is no HTTP call here

Comment: No idea what you mean. It's required by `constructor(private http: Http,`

Comment: You need to fill your get parameters(). All the purpose of dependency injection is explained on this doc page  :  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/adding-pages/  (check the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using TypeScript you need to define the provider as `private` or `public` in the constructor and this will automatically create an instance of the provider within the page class, for example:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private storageService: StorageService)  {
        this.storageService.getUser().then(user => {
          this.user = JSON.parse(user);  
        }).catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
        });    
    }
```

Other replies to your question provide the JavaScript solution which won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need a static `parameters` getter in Ionic like:

```
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/profile.html',
    providers: [StorageService]
})
export class ProfilePage {

    static get parameters() {
      return [[Http], [StorageService]];
    }

    constructor(private http: Http, storageService: StorageService)  {
        this.storageService.getUser().then(user => {
          this.user = JSON.parse(user);  
        }).catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a method Angular DI uses to figure out what needs to get passed to `constructor(...)`. The array returned needs to be an array of types in the same order as the constructor parameters. In the above case DI looks up a provider for `Http` and `StorageService` and passes them to the constructor. I don't know Ionic but it seems this way is required there. In normal Angular2 apps DI can get the information from the types in the constructor signature. It also works like explained above in ES5. I guess the build tool used for Ionic (Babel?) doesn't retain this type information.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was using typescript incorrectly.

Had to declare storageService as below:

```
constructor(private http: Http,private storageService: StorageService)  {
```

i.e I was missing the **private** keyword